# How const variable and const pointer in C++ are treated by compiler and operating system

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

I understand the abstract functionality of these tricks with "const" are for security issues to not let a programmer unintentionally change things, or to not mess things intentionally, or by accident between different programmers of same project (correct me if I am wrong).

What unclear is:

1. How this commitment (to be unchanged) is achieved by means of compiler, operating system (processes, threads), hardware (CPU, RAM) related, etc - i.e. "how whole system 'marks' this cell(s) to treat in such a special way".
2. Does using "const" in a (C/C++) code degrade a performance, for extremely efficient applications, and does it depend on compiler (if yes - please specify on which it does)?

Comment: "Does using "const" in a (C/C++) code degrade a performance", nope; if anything it will help performance.

Comment: The `const` has nothing to do with an operating system, unless it is in the operating system source code.  The `const` is only seen by the compiler.

Answer (score 7):

To answer both of your questions at once:
`const` will never degrade performance, if anything it will increase performance. This is because the compiler is allowed to make certain assumptions when variables are declared `const`. They can't be changed, so the compiler can use this to optimize your code by either refactoring parts of the consts or adding the values of these consts to a read-only data segment, allowing faster lookup.

`const_cast`ing this `const` away (lying to the compiler) while the data is stored in a read-only segment and trying to overwrite it will result in undefined behaviour which is why the compiler can rely on the programmer not doing this and can therefore increase speed.

The compiler is the only one responsible for optimizing this part, not any of the "*operating system (processes, threads), hardware (CPU, RAM)*".

Comment: Here's a nice example of how using `const` increases performance :) https://youtu.be/zBkNBP00wJE?t=27m13s

Answer (score 5):

> I understand the abstract functionality of these tricks with "const" are for security issues

Well, `const`ness isn't a trick, and it's not a security issue in the sense that phrase is normally used

> ... not let a programmer unintentionally change things ...

Yes, `const` tells the compiler - and other developers including your future self - that you don't *intend* to mutate something

> ... or to not mess things intentionally ...

No, because you can simply use `const_cast` to get around it (where the underlying object is genuinely mutable). You just can't do it *accidentally*.

> ... How this commitment (to be unchanged) is achieved by means of compiler ...

That's it. That's everything. The compiler refuses to compile code which mutates `const` objects. If code that mutates `const` objects doesn't compile, nothing needs to be done at runtime, and nothing is.

There are *other* protections, depending on your OS and hardware platform, against writing to regions of memory your process shouldn't be able to change: see for example the UNIX world's SEGV, which is typically enforced by your memory address-mapping hardware and OS working together.

These runtime concepts aren't directly expressed in the language, although they do affect how the language can be implemented on a given platform.

> ... Does using "const" in a (C/C++) code degrade a performance ...

No, `const` is normally used to express more clearly how your code is intended to behave, and this extra information sometimes allows the compiler to make *more* optimizations. I can't think of an obvious reason why it would make anything slower, unless it forces otherwise-avoidable copies.

Answer (score 2):

You are mistaken in thinking this is for security reasons: in fact the `const` keyword is not enforced by anything except the compiler. Even the compiler though can be ordered to ignore the `const` keyword by means of a `const`-cast.

As such there are no performance considerations associated with `const` at runtime (there may be at compile time as the compiler may use it to optimize code differently).

Comment: So I understand operating system doesn't know certain variable object is const or not in code. It means in runtime, if code flow tries to change the const variable or object - this situation is impossible, and compiler will prevent it by error.

Comment: The compiler will prevent modification of `const` objects (producing an error) - but as I said even this can be overcome by a simple cast. At runtime the system and OS has no awareness of const memory at all, thus its not a security feature (malicious code could trivially modify it)

Answer (score 2):

This [article](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/081.htm) by Herb Sutter answers most of your questions.

When a variable is `const`, the compiler assumes that the variable has not been changed in this scope, and uses that information to optimize the code.

Any attempt to modify it will result in undefined behavior:

> Except that any class member declared mutable (7.1.1) can be modified,
>   any attempt to modify a const object during its lifetime (3.8) results
>   in undefined behavior.

Comment: I won't DV, but that's a comment. When you have enough rep you'll be able to post comments ( I know that's a little ridiculous but them the rules ).

Comment: [Link-only answers are not good and will become invalid when the link rots](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/230282). You must at least summary some information from the link, otherwise your answer will get downvoted and/or deleted http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298957/995714

Answer (score 1):

> How this commitment (to be unchanged) is achieved by means of
>   compiler, operating system (processes, threads), hardware (CPU, RAM)
>   related, etc - i.e. "how whole system 'marks' this cell(s) to treat in
>   such a special way".

`const` enforces a read-only contract, and breaching that contract will always be caught at compile-time - for a **correct** (standard conforming code) code; and with the exception of `const_cast`.

The compiler typically knows its target architecture very well. And using `const` correctly may help it structure the code generated in special ways to improve *safety* and *perhaps speed*. Note: that `const` will never degrade speed unless your Compiler is broken.

`const` objects can be kept in read-only memory, or special memory that can be marked as read-only (which enforces a form of hardware safety, an attempt to write after marking the memory as read-only will trigger an Access Violation Exception.

> Does using "const" in a (C/C++) code degrade a performance, for
>   extremely efficient applications, and does it depend on compiler (if
>   yes - please specify on which it does)?

No, it doesn't. If it does, that compiler is buggy.